# Why aren't necessary header files included in the project?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, header-files

I've often downloaded a C/C++ project and tried to compile it just to play with it.  Almost 100% of the time the `make` or `configure` command fails, I go part way down a dependency tree, encounter an error I don't know how to solve, and give up.  This may be a wider issue than just header files, but it seems like fairly often the `make` process requires there to be some .h files for a specific version of a library in a specific place, and they're not there on my system.

If the project needs these specific header files, why doesn't the author copy them into the project source tree?  Isn't it insane to require a development machine to be set up in such a specific way, in general?  What if someone wants to work on two projects, and they require conflicting versions of the header files?

One obvious solution would be to include a Dockerfile for the build process, but I'm interested in how this situation arose in the first place and whether there's some rationale for not just including the necessary header files, which seems like at least a partial solution.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a question you ask of the author of the project you downloaded?    There are many possible explanations.  For example, if the project makes use of libraries from other projects, there might be a simple assumption that both the project you have downloaded AND projects it depends on would be downloaded before attempting to build.

Comment: Maybe insane is the wrong word, but certainly inconvenient in the case where you want to work on two projects that need conflicting header files.  I guess I do think it's insane anyway, and I want to know if I'm wrong.  Some languages handle dependencies in a much more explicit way and keep them with the project, and I don't see any disadvantage to doing it that way.

Comment: @Peter I've tried running `make` enough times to see a general pattern though.  It almost never works without some hacking around, whereas `npm install` (for NodeJS) for example almost always just works

Comment: Including the headers files (assuming no licensing issues) is next to useless. You need matching library files (static or dynamic) of the right version on your system.

Comment: Including  just the headers obviously wouldn't be enough, you need the actual library code too. And sometimes that's pretty big; I wrote an application using the GTK+ toolkit for instance, and the toolkit is much much bigger than my code. Obviously (?) I can't bundle up GTK+ into my code, that would be very impractical.

Comment: You may provide some examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What good would the header files be? You need the actual library, not just the header files.

So why don't they include the whole library?

- Some libraries are very big. Much bigger than the program.
- Because they are big, compiling them takes a long time.
- You don't want to have a separate copy of every library installed on your computer for every project. It's a waste of space and what happens if two different versions try to talk to each other?
- Libraries get updated, and you don't want to have to update your project every time the library gets updated.
- Copyright means you can't legally give away copies of the library without permission. Usually the library's creator gives you permission. Sometimes they don't.

Comment: So bundling the header files with the project would move the error from compile time to (potentially) runtime?  It seems like in either case you're kind of "on your own" in making sure the library is installed (whereas e.g. `apt-get install` resolves it for you).  Kind of being devil's advocate here but why not bundle the header files for compilation and assume the lib is there (instead of assuming the header file is there as most `make`s seem to do and failing at compile time)?  Just because a compile time error is better than a runtime one?

Comment: @user987356 Link time, most likely. If they bundled the header file then the header file might not match the library you actually have installed.

Comment: @user987356 By the way, this is why you should think about whether using a library is a good idea, when you are writing a program, not just use every single library you feel like.

Comment: @user987356 - Imagine you are building a project that relies on several additional libraries, each of which is a separate project.  Which would you prefer?  Option 1:  compilation fails due to headers not being found.   Diagnostics give information about which header was not found.   Option 2:  Compilation succeeds due to headers being found. Linking fails due to libraries associated with those headers not being found. Diagnostics give a mix of information about missing libraries in some cases and mangled names of symbols not found in other cases